# Multiple imputation with a Cox model

Tags: cox-model, multiple-imputation

I'm doing a study on 52 patients with breast cancers and looking for predictive factors of death.
I have 17 variables to test for predictive value with some with 20% of missing data (some categorical and some continuous).
I used the mice package to produce multiple imputation of missing data successfully. I have in this exemple 2 imputations done. Cox model works great on the two imputations separately. But after the use of the pool function, I have 'NaN' for p and 95%CI.
I'm working with MICE 3.1 and R 3.5.
Thank you in advance for your help

> imp <- mice(kp_sub, m=2, maxit=10, method='cart', blocks = c(factor_var,conti_var, ev_var))
>
> summary(with(imp, exp=coxph(Surv(sg_delai,sg_ev)~folfirinox)), exponentiate = TRUE,  conf.int = 0.95)
>
> ```
>           term  estimate std.error  statistic   p.value  conf.low conf.high
>   1 folfirinox1 0.7919579 0.6264833 -0.3723117 0.7096608 0.2319736  2.703744
>   2 folfirinox1 0.7919579 0.6264833 -0.3723117 0.7096608 0.2319736  2.703744
> ```
>
> summary(pool(with(imp, exp=coxph(Surv(sg_delai,sg_ev)~folfirinox))), exponentiate = TRUE,  conf.int = 0.95)
>
> ```
>                 estimate std.error  statistic  df p.value 2.5 % 97.5 %
>     folfirinox1 0.7919579 0.6264833 -0.3723117 NaN     NaN   NaN    NaN
> ```

Comment: Does this happen with more than 2 imputations?

Comment: It is extremely suspicious that your two imputations give the same result to seven significant figures

Comment: I agree with @mdewey and suspect this is some sort of coding error. But coding questions are off topic here.

Comment: You should post this question on stackoverflow and label it as "R"! This website is about statistics, that one about coding/programming!

Answer (score 0):

The dfcom argument of pool() in mice 3.1.3 solve this